# Mongoose generar una multiplicacion

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Cordial Saludo, agradezco a la comunidad Toda su colaboración, realmente de antemano pido disculpas por la formulación de la pregunta pero hasta ahora estoy empezando en la plataforma, nuevamente agradezco su ayuda.

tengo funcionando un Schema:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const analisisSchema = new Schema({
    PerfilDelUsuario: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ValorDelaHora: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    Parametro: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ValorDelParametro: {
        type: Number,
        required: true 
    },

    Periodo: {
        type: String,
        require: true

}, { timestamps: true })

module.exports = model('analisis', analisisSchema);
```

---

En la llave Periodo estoy guardando los datos de una lista de aplicacion, que viene de un Select, hay mas datos que se envían a la base de datos, pero no lo adjunto para no hacer extenso el comentario.

```html
<select name="Periodo" class="form-control">
<option value="ANUAL">Anual</option>
<option value="SEMESTRAL">Semestral</option>
<option value="MENSUAL">Mensual</option>
<option value="DIARIO">Diario</option>
</select>
```

---

Para complementar la pregunta, los datos se están enviando por el method="POST", a la ruta:

```
router.post('/analisis/nuevo-analisis', isAuthenticated, createNewanalisis);
```

y el controlador que me guarda en mongodb es:

```
// crear nuevo parametro de analisis (validado ok)
analisisCtrl.createNewanalisis = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(new analisis(req.body));
    const {PerfilDelUsuario, ValorDelaHora, Parametro, ValorDelParametro, Periodo} = req.body;
    const Analisis = new analisis({ PerfilDelUsuario, ValorDelaHora, Parametro, ValorDelParametro, Periodo});
    Analisis.user = req.user.id;
    await Analisis.save();
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Analisis agregado Satisfactoriamente');
    res.redirect('/analisis/volver-analisis')
};
```

el arreglo en donde voy a usar lo guardado, es una tabla que handlebars va a recorrer:

```
{{#each Analisis}}
<tr>
<td>{{@index}}</td>
<td>{{Parametro}}</td>
<td>{{ValorDelParametro}}</td>
<td>{{Tipo}}</td>
<td>{{Periodo}}</td>
<td>{{Reducible}}</td>
<td>{{TotalAño}}</td>
<td>
<a href="" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-dark">Habilitar</a>
<a href="/analisis/eliminar/{{_id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST"
type="button" class="btn-sm btn-danger">eliminar</a>
<a href="" type="button" class="btn-sm btn-info">Editar</a>
</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

1. la idea es volver Primero una variable numérica cuando se guarde en mongo las opciones de la lista;
   ejemplo que guarde "ANUAL" y el valor de 365 para después solo usar el 365 y multiplicarlo.
2. Segundo multiplicar la opción escogida con ValorDelParametro, para exportar los resultados a una tabla,

lo he intentado pero el option solo me guarda un value en la base de datos, me podrían ayudar;

### de ante mano muchas gracias por su tiempo y atencion prestada.

Comment: En tus atributos `value` de cada `checkbox`simplemente coloca el valor que deseas, por ejemplo: `<option value="365">Anual</option>`. Luego ya podrás enviar el dato seleccionado al `backend`. Para poder ayudarte correctamente es necesario que muestres cómo envías los datos al `backend`, y además, cómo los recibes en el mismo y cómo los procesas una vez recibidos. Saludos

Comment: Mauricio muchas gracias por tu ayuda, los datos los envió por el method="POST", a una ruta que me conecta con el controlador que me guarda los datos en mongodb, estoy usando mongoose y nodejs; no puedo guardar 365 por que después recorro la base de datos mongodb y extraigo ese numero para mostrar al usuario, y no quiero que vea 365, si no Anual, el 365 solo lo necesito yo para mis cálculos. voy agregar la información que me pides, nuevamente muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Creo que entendí en parte lo que deseas. Quieres salvar los datos que vienen desde el cliente, para luego, volcar los datos salvados en una tabla, pero dicha tabla contiene un valor que no está presente en tu modelo. Dicho valor es `ValorDelParametro * <un numero equivalente a ANUAL, MENSUAL, ETC>`. Existen infinidad de formas para hacer esto sin necesidad de crear un campo nuevo en tu modelo. Dime si es correcto esto o lo entendí mal. Saludos

Comment: Mauricio si es eso exactamente lo que pretendo hacer, muchas gracias nuevamente por tu tiempo, es muy valiosa tu ayuda para mi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te comenté con anterioridad, existen infinidad de formas de resolver el problema sin alterar la estructura actual de tus datos. Aquí te mostraré 2 formas basadas en el uso de [métodos de instancia](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) de Mongoose.

**Devolver el valor requerido basados en el valor del atributo `Periodo`**

Podemos crear un método a nivel de instancia, para que al llamar a dicho método en 
el documento devuelto por la consulta, devuelva el valor por el cual debo multiplicar el parámetro.

Llamaremos a dicho método `getMultiply()`, y lo definimos así:

```js
// ...
// Código para definir tu Schema
// ...


// creamos un objeto de métodos en el Schema y definimos una función
analisisSchema.methods = {
  getMultiply: function() {
    let multiply = undefined;
    switch(this.Periodo) {
      case 'ANUAL':
        multiply = 365;
        break;
      case 'SEMESTRAL':
        multipliy = 180;
        break;
      case 'MENSUAL':
        multiply = 30;
        break;
      case 'DIARIO':
        multiply = 1;
        break;
      default:
        multiply = 1;
    }
    return multiply;
  }
}

// ...
// Resto de acciones con tu Schema
// ...
```

Con esto, cuando obtenemos un documento (o varios documentos) podemos usar este método para saber el valor por el que podemos multiplicar.

Ejemplo 1 sólo documento:

```js
Analisis.findOne(query, (error, doc) => {
  // ...
  // lógica para manejo de errores
  // ...

  // obtenemos el valor para el documento:
  let multiply = doc.getMultiply();

  // ...
  // lógica para hacer las operaciones restantes
  // ...
});
```

Ejemplo con múltiples documentos:

```js
Analisis.find(query, (error, docs) => {
  // ...
  // lógica para manejo de errores
  // ...

  // obtenemos el valor para cada documento y lo almacenamos en array, asociando cada documento con su valor:
  let list = [];
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    list.push({ doc: doc, multiply: doc.getMultiply()});
  });

  // ...
  // lógica para hacer las operaciones restantes
  // ...
});
```

**Devolver un documento que contenga todos los valores más el valor `multiply`**

Otra solución es crear un método `getValues()` para tu modelo de datos, el cual te devuelva un objeto con el valor adicional de acuerdo a si el documento contiene un valor de *Período* que coincida con 'ANUAL', 'SEMESTRAL', etc.

Este método simplemente crea un nuevo objeto con un campo (que llamaremos `multiply`) y le asigna un valor de acuerdo al valor del campo `Periodo`. Luego copia los valores del documento almacenado en BD en este nuevo documento y lo devuelve. Para ello usamos [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign) y nos apoyaremos en un atributo llamado `_doc` que posee cada instancia de Documento de Mongoose.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const analisisSchema = new Schema({
  // tus atributos
}, { timestamps: true });

analisisSchema.methods = {
  getValues: function() {
    let multiply = undefined;
    switch(this.Periodo) {
      case 'ANUAL':
        multiply = 365;
        break;
      case 'SEMESTRAL':
        multipliy = 180;
        break;
      case 'MENSUAL':
        multiply = 30;
        break;
      case 'DIARIO':
        multiply = 1;
        break;
      default:
        multiply = 1;
    }
    let values = { multiply };
    Object.assign(values, this._doc);
    return values;
  }
}

module.exports = model('analisis', analisisSchema);
```

El objeto `this._doc` es un atributo *protegido* del objeto [`Document`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Document).

Ejemplo de uso para 1 documento:

```js
Analisis.findOne(query, (error, doc) => {
  // ...
  // lógica para manejo de errores
  // ...

  // obtenemos un objeto que contiene todos los valores incluyendo 'multiply':
  let values = doc.getValues();

  // ...
  // lógica para hacer las operaciones restantes
  // ...
});
```

Ejemplo para mútiples documentos:

```js
Analisis.find(query, (error, docs) => {
  // ...
  // lógica para manejo de errores
  // ...

  // obtenemos la lista de documentos con los valores requeridos:
  let list = [];
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    list.push(doc.getvalues());
  });

  // ...
  // lógica para hacer las operaciones restantes
  // ...
});
```

Con esto tienes 2 formas de obtener el valor que necesitas, basado en el valor del campo `Periodo` de tu modelo.

Como te comenté en un principio, existen muchas otras formas, algunas implican modificación en tu modelo de datos. Yo opté por esta que son menos invasivas y además se convierten en un añadido a tus datos, al ser métodos de instancia.

Comment: Mauricio De manera muy respetuosa, agradezco mucho tu ayuda con este problema, me ha sido de mucha utilidad; gracias por ser tan claro con la explicación;  hasta ahora respondo por que estaba digiriendo un poco la respuesta.

Comment: @deibydquiroz pues si tienes alguna duda al respecto puedes formularla. Entiendo que debe ser todo algo nuevo si estás empezando con Mongoose. Saludos

Comment: @ MauricioContreras, como puedo recorrer un objeto y sacar la propiedad que necesito, para hacer la operacion en el back end y no desde mongodb, ya que me presenta problema al traer la variable creada dentro de mongodb; desde mi back end he e intentado recorrer el objeto y sacarla con Object.entries(), pero me toma todo el objeto como uno solo, me lo pasa completo; Mauricio que pena preguntar tanto de ante mano te agradezco mucho.

Comment: Hola, no entiendo bien a lo que te refieres. Si tienes un objeto, digamos `obj`. Para obtener el valor de una propiedad conocida, basta con usar la notación de punto: `obj.propiedad` o usar la notación de corchetes: `obj['propiedad']`. ¿Esa es tu duda?

Comment: @  Mauricio Contreras, asi guardo el objeto, pero no puedo acceder con obj [ ], al atributo  Periodo, si me hago entender? muchas gracias.                                                                                     
{
  _id: 5e9f4cb9716d580440f15f7a,
  PerfilDelUsuario: 'EMPRESARIO',
  ValorDelaHora: 123000,
  Parametro: 'ELECTRICIDAD',
  ValorDelParametro: 12300,
  Periodo: 'ANUAL',
  Tipo: 'FIJO',
  Reducible: 'SI',
  TipoMoneda: '($) Dolar USD',
  user: '5e849055d40cf321301261c4',
  createdAt: 2020-04-21T19:42:49.918Z,
  updatedAt: 2020-04-21T19:42:49.918Z,
  __v: 0
}

Comment: Es mejor que hagas una pregunta en el sitio, porque la verdad no lo pillo. No estoy seguro de lo que intentas hacer. Saludos